# Facebook url not opening in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I am new to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit. Don't know what stuff is going wrong but after connecting through Mobile Broadband, internet is working fine except www.facebook.com. Is there any additional setting required? Pls guide.

Comment: open terminal and run `ping facebook.com`.

Comment: ping test is succeeding but url still shows loading in firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to connect via the terminal and see if you can post a HTTP GET request:

1. open Terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T)
2. open a telnet connection:

   telnet facebook.com 80
3. Type the following, and add a linefeed (press enter):

   GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
   host: facebook.com
4. You should see a response:

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://facebook.com/index.htm
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
X-FB-Debug: /mV/7oC9NJwnGs7OSY6OfWyxarr+MTUbgB/HLnXRnTBTESg3RBHWN81weo2B8srQarcE+GAJHQZI/t7UIgkYWg==
Date: Mon, 04 Jul 2016 16:56:49 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0

If you're getting information from the site, you know it's not the OS, and likely a browser issue.  Make sure you don't have invalid proxies setup for example.

Comment: Yes, 'System Proxy' was default option. After selecting 'No Proxy', it works. Thanks

Comment: Good. Glad it works now

Answer (score 0):

Is there any firewall that could be stopping a connection? If so you could check around for proxies to bypass. Otherwise it may be something with your ISP. Hide.me seems to be rather popular, although I havent used it. You can find it here https://hide.me/en/proxy